# Check for the existence of a column in v$database in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am familiar how to check for a column name in a table or view by using the following query

```
select count(*) 
from user_tab_columns 
where table_name = [name of view] 
and column_name = [name of column]
```

But, this doesn't work for a column that I am trying to check for in v$database.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v$database` is actually a public synonym for the `v_$database` view owned by `sys` (checked in Oracle 12).

So to get column information:

1. You can't use `user_tab_columns`, because that only considers tables/views owned by the current user. But the view you're interested in is owned by `sys`.
2. You can't use the synonym name `v$database`. You have to use the actual view name: `v_$database`.

So you can use either `dba_tab_columns` or `all_tab_columns` like so:

```
select count(*) 
from dba_tab_columns 
where table_name = 'V_$DATABASE' 
and column_name = [name of column]
```

**EDIT**:

Another way that is less dependant on the actual view name in `sys`, which I guess could change between Oracle database versions, would be to join with `dba_synonyms`:

```
select count(*)
  from dba_synonyms s
  join dba_tab_columns c
    on c.owner = s.table_owner
   and c.table_name = s.table_name
   and c.column_name = [column name]
 where s.owner = 'PUBLIC'
   and s.synonym_name = 'V$DATABASE'
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine on my machine using the synonym. Oracle version 11.2. Perhaps that restriction is in older versions, and no longer exists?

Comment: @mathguy: Or the opposite.  I tested in v12, and I get no results if I query `dba_tab_columns` with `table_name = 'V$DATABASE'`. What owner/table_name values do you see when you query `dba_tab_columns`? Is it possible that the view name itself changed between versions?

Comment: Hm... Good call. I was wrong; with 'V$DATABASE' I get a count of 0; the synonym is not in DBA_TAB_COLUMNS. I get proper counts with 'V_$DATABASE' just as you said. HOWEVER, in v12 I tested and the object V_$DATABASE does not exist; however, I get proper counts and everything with V$DATABASE!

Comment: The owner I see (in 11.2 at least) is SYS, but keep in mind these are all one-user installations, just for my own learning. Things may be different on a "real" system.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select *
from dba_tab_columns 
where table_name = 'V_%DATABASE%'
```